# How to change maxWidth of MatDialog when it is already open?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, frontend

I know I can set `maxWidth` when opening `MatDialog`, but what if the dialog is already open?

I am opening the dialog like

```
    const dialog = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      maxWidth: maxWidth,
      width: '100%'
    });
```

There is a function `updateSize()`, but it is for changing `width` but not `maxWidth`.

For example,

```
this.dialogRef.updateSize("80rem");
```

will change the `width` but not the `max-width`.

So, are there any way to achieve that, changing `maxWidth` when a dialog is already open?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post an example of your current attempt using `updateSize()`?

Comment: @JacobStamm Updated. Please take a look. Thanks